# Estimated completion time of forEach() method

Tags: javascript, time

I have a forEach() method that looks like this:

```
channels.forEach((channel) => {
   var start = new Date().getTime();

   fields.forEach(function(field) {
      //stuff done here
   });

   var end = new Date().getTime();
   var time = (end - start);
   console.log(time)
});
```

I'd like to take the execution time for the first channel in the forEach() method, and estimate the rest of the loops based on that first completion time. Not sure if this is set up correctly for that, or where I should go from here

Comment: are you sure sampling the first run is a good estimate for all the runs? if that is so, all you need to do is to make time a global variable, and multiple it by the number of runs that will be performed by the forEach loop

Comment: Yeah all of the data for each channel is extremely similar. They don't care about pin point accuracy, just an estimate. I'll give that a shot! Thanks @Ji_in_coding

Comment: Do you want to show a estimated duration, or what do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Cache effects mean it's very likely the first iteration will be the slowest, possibly by an order of magnitude. Not to mention if the JS engine identifies this as a hotspot and JITs it. This technique is likely to produce poor estimations of the total run time. A rolling-average method is advisable for long-running code.

Answer (score 1):

It is fundamentally correct, but you are printing the elapsed time of each channel, instead of just once, unless you are cancelling the test afterwards. I would suggest that you measure the time it takes to run over all the channels and take the average time for all, as this value will be more consistent/scientific for lack of a better word.

Also, the regular Date().getTime() function only has a precision down to one millisecond. You could switch to a library with a more precise nanosecond timer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` as shown below:

```
channels.forEach((channel) => {
    console.time("time taken");

    fields.forEach(function(field) {
       //stuff done here
    });

    console.timeEnd("time taken");
 });
```